# Windows Azure website suspended due to exceeding CPU quota

Tags: azure, quota

Something strange happened today. My website on windowsAzure was suspended and inaccessible because my site had exceeded the CPU quotum. I am running the website in shared mode, but I had removed all quota. So why is my website suspended, I thought I would pay for the extra usage, not that my website would be suspended. What is happening here? And what should I do to prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Web Sites [pricing details page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/), you'll see that CPU utilization has a daily quota:
[image: websites quotas]

For Shared Mode websites, you'll get CPU-minutes daily. This would be the quota you're exceeding. At this point, you'd need to ramp up to Reserved instances (or find ways to reduce CPU utilization in your app).

Look at [this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-scale-websites/) for more info about Web Sites tiers and scaling.

Comment: It could be *any* Free or Shared web site in your subscription that exceeded its CPU quota.  When that happens, **ALL** sites in your subscription are suspended until the 24-hour accounting period is up and a new day starts.